# BorderLayout.SOUTH component always shown on Android when editing text field in Codenameone

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm having a problem on Android, but not IOS.
I have a basic screen where i have 10 TextFields inside a scrollable Y_AXIS container; i have this placed on a BorderLayout.CENTRE container underneath.
I then have a Button in the same base container but in BorderLayout.SOUTH.

When the user clicks on any TextField, situation to edit it, the keyboard displays and it places the content of the BorderLayout.SOUTH, ie. the button, above the keyboard, hiding some of the fields. I want the Button to be hidden underneath the keyboard as per IOS.

As i've only just realised that this happens, i now have some screens where it doesn't occur if i have a certain mix of containers and fields, some screens where it squashes my text fields up, and some where it just hides another field lower down that i want a user to see.

I've attached a basic page showing this. Note this is fine on simulator, given no keyboard is shown.
Many thanks

```
   public class Keyboard {
    private Form currentForm = new Form("", new BorderLayout());
    public void buildPage() {
        Container c = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        Container y = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        y.setScrollableY(true);

        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());
        y.add(new TextField());

        c.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, y);
        c.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buildButton());

        currentForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, c);
        currentForm.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x65363);
        currentForm.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        currentForm.setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);
        currentForm.show();
    }
    private Component buildButton() {
        Button button = new Button("Hide this button");
        return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the UI to border layout you disable scrolling implicitly. This is good as you can only have one scrollable element in the hierarchy per axis.

On iOS when the keyboard opens the scroll region grows. Since the button is excluded from the scroll region it's always visible. Again this is by design e.g. it can keep an "OK" button in view which might be the desired behavior.

If you don't want that behavior you need to use a scrollable container. Unfortunately the moment the UI is scrollable it's hard to implement features like placing the button at the bottom of the screen.

Our system has a hard time detecting the bottom of the screen when the UI is scrollble as the hierarchy sizes can change dynamically and the bottom can be anywhere. This might be doable with the new GUI builder's layered layout which is pretty elaborate.

Comment: From the time i've put in to this, it's good to know i'm not going mad. I'll do a redesign to have a scrollable Y-AXIS as the common base container, and have 'Next>' type buttons positioned in-view underneath the fields. Where the page is large i will use command button in the toolbar. I always felt the page looks friendlier with the button at the bottom of the page than the toolbar, hence my reticence in putting it there. Thanks for the response.